# How do I change the saturation settings on my Pixma Pro 100?

Tags: canon, color-management, printer, saturation, color-red

I just purchased a Pixma Pro 100 to replace my Epson R2000 after it died; sad to say, Epson is no longer carrying the R2000.

My prints on the Pro 100 are desaturated, and a little on the dark side. My reds are not displaying properly either.

I have tried the common settings, as well as PRO MODE, but I still have the same results.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the driver color correction entirely, and using the proper ICC profiles from the software you are using to print? Generally speaking, using the printer driver to control color will usually result in improper color. The most accurate way to print is with Lightroom or Photoshop, using an ICC profile generated explicitly for your paper and printer.

Comment: I'm having the same problem printing from photoshop using my new pixma pro-100. Using Canon Pro Luster Paper, Quality set to Fine, color handled by photoshop profile LU 1/2 Canon Pro Luster, Perceptual rendering, send 16-bit data, black point compensation off. Prints are way desaturated, red are more maroon. I don't know what the problems is.

Comment: I think the problem is when I convert from working Pro Photo color space to Canon LU 1/2 Pro Luster Paper, if I do the conversion in photoshop before printing (Edit->Convert Profile) the colors change drastically and look much more accurate to what's printed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you been closing the application after printing?  I'm not sure exactly what causes it, but when I was doing prints out of Lightroom the other day on my Pro-1 and I closed lightroom.  The exact moment I closed the program, the print (mid-line) developed the problem you describe.  Reprinting and not closing the program fixed the issue completely.

My theory on the problem is that the ICC profile was dropped from processing when I closed lightroom.  At the time I was printing on Canon Photo Pro Platinum paper.  If your situation doesn't match mine exactly, the problem is still probably some information not getting to the printer from the application about the color space.  Perhaps try printing from one of the packages that comes with the printer.  Easy-PhotoPrint EX has been my prefered stand alone tool.

Also, if this is helpful and fixes the problem.  Please let me know what about it you changed.  I'm very curious as to what information dropped out to cause this problem when I was printing as well.